# Laravel components in production errors

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a weird problem with Laravel components. They work perfectly in local environment but in production they make errors about undefined variables, even when variables have default values. And second - they can't show images from storage. For example, this line

```
$course->preview = url('storage/images/'.$preview->thumbnail);
```

totally ignores `storage/images/` and turns into just `1669011278.png` for example.

Components class names start with uppercase letters, I've tried to clear cache with

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Tried to make a link to storage on hosting but nothing works. Images from views work like they should, the problem is with the components. There is something I'm missing here, but I can't find out what exactly.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly the error is ? also sample component that not working ?

Comment: @xenooooo, sure, `Undefined variable $class`, but variable is defined inside the related class

Comment: did you run the `view:cache`  command ?

Comment: @xenooooo yes but no luck

Comment: My god I'm stupid. Found out the folders containing the components ALSO should start with uppercase letters. Now it works

Comment: Well. Congrats !